# Buttons/toggles not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

So I'm trying to figure out why my buttons don't work on a checklist app I'm making.  The idea is that you enter into the text field, delete it with the deleteBtn, and should be able to strike-through the text when the doneBox is clicked.

At the moment, the elements all get added to the table in my HTML, but the delete button doesn't do anything and checking the done box doesn't strike anything

Here's the JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click",".btn-danger", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove;
      });

  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newThing = $("#newThing").val().trim();
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var deleteBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-danger").append("Delete");
    var doneBox = $("<input>").attr("type", "checkbox").attr("class", "doneBox").attr("data-state", "not-checked");
    var toDoThis = $("<td>").addClass("word-td").append(newThing).append(deleteBtn).prepend(doneBox)
    newRow.append(toDoThis);
    $("tbody").append(newRow);
    $("#newThing").val("").focus();
  }); 
  $(document).on("click", ".doneBox", function(){
    var status = $(this).attr("data-state");
    if (status === "not-checked"){
      $(this).parent().attr("class", "done");
      $(this).attr("data-state", "checked")
    }
    else{
      $(this).parent().removeClass();
      $(this).attr("data-state", "not-checked");
    }
  });
});
```

the css is just a text decoration for the ".done" class

Comment: Can you add the HTML as well?

Comment: Try removing the angle brackets from your selectors - tr instead of <tr> for instance

Comment: Rather, try closing them, either like `<tr />` ,or preferably like `<tr></tr>`

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console?

Comment: @j08691 there was no error message.  it just wasn't doing anything

Comment: You would definitely get errors in the console based on the code you posted and the answer you chose.

Comment: @j08691 The answer rank posted below fixed it.  everything is doing what it's supposed to do.  just kept missing those brackets when I was looking it over.

Comment: Why reflect the checkbox's state as a data attribute when it can be read directly with `.is(':checked')`?

Comment: @roaamer-1888: because I'm extremely n00bish and that was my work-around for not knowing how to do things the right way.

Comment: @CBMoate, I love honesty :-)

Comment: @Roamer-1888:  used the method you suggested.  Saved many lines.  Much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing brackets in line number 3 of your code.

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ranakrunal9's answer appears to be correct,  but here's the whole thing written more efficiently :

```
$(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    $(".btn-primary").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newThing = $('#newThing');
        $('<tr><td class="word-td"><input type="checkbox" class="doneBox" />' + newThing.val().trim() + '<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td></tr>').appendTo('tbody'));
        newThing.empty().focus();
    }); 
    $(document).on('click', '.doneBox', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('td').addClass('done');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('td').removeClass();
        }
    });
});
```